# If combobox selected then show

Tags: c#, combobox, selectedindexchanged

I have to load a form and in this form I want to hide certain labels and text-boxes. In addition I want to show labels and text-boxes matching the condition`if combo-box selected =="Something"`

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.Text == "Something")
    {
        label1.Show();
        label2.Show();
        textBox1.Show();
        textBox2.Show();
    }
}
```

How do I get these labels and text-boxes shown after I had selected a combo-box

Comment: I assume you are using ASP.NET and not WinForms... make sure you are using something like the following <asp:DropDownList ID="comboBox1" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">

Comment: Is this ASP.NET, WinForms, or WPF?

Answer (score 3):

try

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedValue == "Something")
    {
        label1.Visible = true;
        label2.Visible = true;
        textBox1.Visible = true;
        textBox2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Weblover Try if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.SelectedValue))

Answer (score 0):

I would try it like so, no need for an if:

```
label1.Visible = label2.Visible = textBox1.Visible = textBox2.Visible = 
           comboBox1.SelectedValue.toString() == "Something";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = (ComboBoxItem)ComboBox.SelectedItem;

    if (item == null) 
        return;

    var content = (string) item.Content;
    if(content == "Something")
    {
        label1.Visible = true;
        label2.Visible = true;
        textBox1.Visible = true;
        textBox2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to take a closer look at how the ComboBox and it's related properties function. The problem you're having is probably related to the fact that the ".Text" field doesn't reflect the currently selected item.

**SelectedItem:** Gets or sets currently selected item in the ComboBox.
*Based on ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted*

**Text:** Gets or sets the text associated with this control. (Overrides Control.Text.)
*setting the text value will change the current value of the combobox*

**SelectedValue:** Gets or sets the value of the member property specified by the ValueMember property. (Inherited from ListControl.)
*Based on ListControl.SelectedValueChanged*

Source [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Further reading at [dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/combobox).

Build this demo program I made for learning to see it in action.

[image: ComboBox demo]

---

### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="220" Width="711" Background="#FF6937D4">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,38,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="333"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" SelectedValuePath="Content" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="comboSelectChanged">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Zero" Tag="Tag_Zero"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="One" Tag="Tag_One"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Two" Tag="Tag_Two"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Three" Tag="Tag_Three"/>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,66,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="333"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,94,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="333"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,122,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="333"/>
    <Label Content="comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="348,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Height="23" Width="215" Padding="7,3,0,0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"/>
    <Label Content="comboBox1.Text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="348,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Height="23" Width="215" Padding="7,3,0,0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"/>
    <Label Content="comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString()" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="348,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Height="23" Width="215" Padding="7,3,0,0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"/>
    <Label Content="comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="348,122,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Height="23" Width="215" Padding="7,3,0,0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,150,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="333"/>
    <Label Content=" (comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content as string" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="348,150,-119,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Height="23" Width="360" Padding="7,3,0,0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnSelect" Content="Select based on value" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="175,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168" Click="btnSelect_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

### XAML.CS

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void comboSelectChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
            textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = comboBox1.Text;
            textBox3.Text = comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
            textBox4.Text = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = (comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content as string;  
         }

        private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            // Winform working code:  comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindString("string");
            // WPF - This REQUIRES "SelectedValuePath="Content"" in XAML combobox def.
            comboBox1.SelectedValue = "Three";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (comboBox1.SelectedValue == "Something")
{
    label1.Visible = true;
    label2.Visible = true;
    textBox1.Visible = true;
    textBox2.Visible = true;
}
}
```

set autoPostback true for dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void cmbPosition_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(cmbPosition.Text =="Staff")
    {
        label11.Visible = true;
        txtRole.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please improve this post. Right now it is a code dump.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void datagrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (datagrid.SelectedItem == null || datagrid.SelectedItem.ToString() == "{NewItemPlaceholder}")
        {
            btnRemove.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else
        {
            btnRemove.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```